# Require curly braces in bash variable expansion

Tags: bash, variable, json

Is there a bash option or another way to make bash to only expand curly-braced variables like `${var}` and ignore regular ones like `$var`?

Update - here is why i want that:
I have a relatively large program written in pure bash and it has to stay in pure bash (it is an installer designed to run on most Linux distributions, we do not want to add additional dependencies).
It has a very simple template engine written in bash. Here is the template parsing code (all of it):

```
function apply_template() {
  local src=$1
  local dst=$2
  local code="
cat<<EOF
$(cat $src)
EOF
"
  eval "$code" > $dst
}
```

It is very simple yet very effective. We have 30 templates that are evaluated using this code. Here is an example:

```
[ {
  "host" : "${primary_node_ip}",
  "access" : {
    "type" : "ssh",
    "user" : "${user}",
    "key" : "id_rsa"
  } ]
```

Bash replaces variables with values, everything is fine.

The problem occurs when we have a template that has "$" signs that should not be treated as variables, for example an nginx config.
If fact it only happens in one template which is an nginx conf.

The perfect solution would be to enable this (non existent as i now know) mode in my "apply_template" function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not. Variable expansion is described in the manual at [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion. *The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, **which are optional*** [...]

If you really really need this

- please explain why (this smells like an XY problem)
- you may be able to pre-process the bash code to escape all `$` that precede an identifier with no punctuation in between.

Comment: Thank you, i provided the explanation in my question. Would probably use pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have some JSON template, similar to what you show in your question:

```bsh
$ cat template
[
  {
    "host": $primary_node_ip,
    "access": {
      "type": $access_type,
      "user": $user,
      "key": $id_rsa
    },
    "comment": $comment
  }
]
```

The things in there that looks like shell variable are actually internal `jq` variables that we can assign values to on the command line of the `jq` JSON tool.  Doing so would additionally encode the values appropriately for inclusion in a JSON document:

```bsh
jq -n -f template \
        --arg primary_node_ip '127.0.0.1' \
        --arg access_type SSH \
        --arg user "$(id -un)" \
        --arg id_rsa "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" \
        --arg comment "$(cat <<-'END'
                Test use only.
                Contact "Adam" at admin@site.example.com
                for more info.
        END
        )"
```

The command above would assign values to the variables used in the document.  Some variables are assigned variables values, and the `$comment` variable is assigned a multi-line text with embedded quotes.

The `-n` option stops `jq` from reading extra input from a file or input stream.  Instead, it will produce the result of the expression in the template file provided via the `-f` option.

Output (example):

```json
[
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "access": {
      "type": "SSH",
      "user": "myself",
      "key": "ssh-rsa AAAAVERYLONGKEY= myself@site.example.com"
    },
    "comment": "Test use only.\nContact \"Adam\" at admin@site.example.com\nfor more info."
  }
]
```

The `jq` tool is available for all Linux distributions that I'm aware of, as well as for all other current Unix variants.

Comment: 1. Your solution only works for JSON documents. I mentioned that i have an nginx config (and also other non-JSON files).
2. Your solution is more complex than mine. At least this is how i see it. 3. To be honest i didn't ask for an alternative solution, i am happy with what i have now - it work perfectly, it is simple to code and to use. Initially i just asked a simple yes or no question and i am absolutely happy with the "no" answer.
I did provided a full explanation because people start asking for it and i don't want to be rude.

I marked the answer that says "no" to my initial question.

Comment: @ScottTiger That's ok. You question states that you have 30 templates like the one you're showing, which is clearly a JSON document. I'm not an Nginx user so I have no knowledge of what kind of files that piece of software uses.  In any case, JSON can't generally include raw text from shell variables unless you encode it first, which `jq` does easily for you. Other common structured document formats are the same, and often require encoding of the data that should be included. My solution uses a single command, your solution employs a shell function which calls `eval` on code read from a file.

Comment: @ScottTiger Since you had a problem with a specific file (the Nginx configuration), I assumed that the file that you showed, the JSON document, was in some way related to that issue. I gave you the solution that would have managed to insert _any_ type of data into a JSON template document.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry for any misunderstanding here. Your solution is clearly better with JSON.